# Error with the image when running a app, after Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-update-app

I just update to new version of Android Studio and my app stop this displaying in the preview screen.

The error that I get is this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > C:\Users\So BE\AndroidStudioProjects\SustainableBusinessCard\app\src\main\res\drawable\SDlogo_black.jpg:
> >     Error: 'S' is not a valid file-based resource name character:
> >     File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or
> >     underscore

I try to change the name of image "SDlogo_black" to "sdlogoblack", but it still does not work, following the suggestion of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931011/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources)

Any help will be appreciated it.

Comment: Change image name with lowercase. Then **clean** and **rebuild** projects.

Comment: Make sure all the names of the images in the drawable folder are in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks @Heisen-Berg I try just the lowercase and did not work, but after using the Menu "Build" I follow your instruction and worked. Thanks a lot! I think you can make a answer.

Comment: You can approve answer. if it helps you @Emanuel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to docs, while naming to resources in Android SDK you have to name it in only `lowercase a-z, 0-9 or underscore`. After naming resource according to docs, just **clean** and **rebuild** your project.